# How can I overload the assignment operator in c++

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, performance, effect, primitive-types

Ive been reading this article: https://www.thc.org/root/phun/unmaintain.html, and Ive been trying to implements steps `Misleading names` (search for `isValid(x)`) and `How To Fix Unused Variable Errors` (#29 under Miscellaneous Techniques).

I wish to do something more useful, (also according to the article) as doing more stuff on less lines is better.

Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to overload the assignment operator for a basic type. I know I could do something like `operator=(&Other o)` if I was using a class, but alas, C/C++ doesn't take after Java by having classes for some basic types...

Comment: Certainly related: [What is the rule of three?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)

Comment: "doing more stuff on less lines is better". Not at the expense of clarity, it isn't!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, I have no idea on how to overload the assignment operator for a basic type. I know I could do something like `operator=(&Other o)` if I was using a class

You cannot overload operators for built-in types in C++. And that's the end of the story.

> but alas, C/C++ doesn't take after Java by having classes for some basic types...

...You make it sound like Java's distinction between `int` and `Integer` is somehow a good thing :)